# Dart get the name of the day by its index: day 0 = Monday, day 1 = Tuesday etc

Tags: flutter, dart, date, time

Is there an easy way in Dart to get the name of the day by its index (taking **localization** into account)?
day 0 = Monday
day 1 = Tuesday
...

I can keep a list of names, but I guess it would be better to use Dart's Date utilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can start at any random date that is a Sunday and increment the days using date format to get the localized name of the day, here's an example code that prints all the days of the week given an index number:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


void main() {
  final sundayDate = DateTime.utc(2022, DateTime.july, 3);
  
  print('Prints the names of all days:');
  for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++) {
    print(DateFormat('EEEE').format(sundayDate.add(Duration(days: i))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class.

```
print(DateFormat.EEEE().format(DateTime.now()));
```

Comment: This would give me the name of a certain Date (today). I'm looking for the name of a specific DAY by index